# SQL statement, using AS clause

Tags: sql

Ok so i'm trying to figure out how to change data is viewed once it is displayed in a select statement. So the table looks like this

**Holiday_Details**

Holiday_Code - Holiday_Desc - Country_Visited

Country_Visited can be either 'USA', 'India', 'China', or 'Spain'.

My question is, in a view statement, how would i use an AS clause to change 'USA' to America? etc

I thought i might have to use a nested select statement but that didn't work.

Comment: `ELSE COUNTRY_VISITED,` shouldn't have a `,` on the end, it should be after the `END AS COUNTRY_VISITED`

Comment: Please read about formatting code blocks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `AS` you need a case:

```
select case
         when country_visited = 'USA' then 'America'
         when country_visited = 'India' THEN 'ASIA'
         when country_visited = 'CHINA' THEN 'ASIA'
         else country_visited 
       end as country_visited,
       ....
from holiday_details
```

Comment: Thank you :) I don't suppose i could be cheeky and ask for help with the syntax here?

Comment: @TomBetts: what do you mean with "*help with the syntax*"? That is a working example. Except for the `...` that is. Which simply is a placeholder for all the other columns.

Comment: Ah maybe i have miss understood the application of the case statement, google is not helping me much. I edit'ed in my attempt but i think i have missapplied your working example

Comment: @TomBetts: see my edit. Each condition needs a `when`. The `ELSE` part is only there is none of the above (`when`) conditions was true.

Comment: @TomBetts: the CASE statement should be documented in the manual of your DBMS. See e.g. here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

Comment: @TomBetts Please don't edit answers into the question.  Makes no sense when you look at it afterward.